# "Missing \endcsname inserted", and "Extra \endcsname." exceptions

Tags: tables, errors, rotating

Recently I had to rotate my table by "sidewaystable" and I got weird exceptions:
in the main.tex file i included the package by `\usepackage{rotating}`

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\caption{ECE(\%) measures with $95\%$ confidence intervals when varying the calibration method, model, and dataset.
The parentheses value shows the percentage of relative improvement of ${\stab}$ over other calibration methods.}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\large
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccc}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Dataset}}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Model}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mathbf{\stab}$}  & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mathbf{\sep}$}   & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Sklearn-Iso}}  & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Sklearn-Platt}}  & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{SBC}}  & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{HB}}  &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{TS}}  & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ETS}} \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{MNIST}}       & CNN    & .19{\smaller\textpm.04}    & .19{\smaller\textpm.04}   & \hfil-                             & \hfil-                             & 8.71{\smaller\textpm.83(97.8\%)}     & .49{\smaller\textpm.09(61.2\%)}   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.29{\smaller\textpm.06(34.4\%)}}   & .27{\smaller\textpm.05(29.6\%)}   \\        
                                      & RF     & .39{\smaller\textpm.06}    & .40{\smaller\textpm.06}   & .90{\smaller\textpm.12(56.6\%)}    & 1.48{\smaller\textpm.07(73.6\%)}   & 3.66{\smaller\textpm.38(89.3\%)}     & .53{\smaller\textpm.04(26.4\%)}   & \hfil-                                                           & \hfil-                 \\        
                                      & GB     & .36{\smaller\textpm.07}    & .35{\smaller\textpm.09}   & 1.74{\smaller\textpm.15(79.3\%)}   & 1.94{\smaller\textpm.13(81.4\%)}   & 8.23{\smaller\textpm.24(95.6\%)}     & .48{\smaller\textpm.08(24.9\%)}   & \hfil-                                                           & \hfil-                 \\ \hline        
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{GTSRB}}       & CNN    & .40{\smaller\textpm.10}    & .38{\smaller\textpm.07}   & \hfil-                             & \hfil-                             & 28.44{\smaller\textpm2.08(98.5\%)}   & .88{\smaller\textpm.32(54.5\%)}   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.11{\smaller\textpm.40(63.9\%)}}   & .99{\smaller\textpm.41(59.5\%)}  \\        
                                      & RF     & .37{\smaller\textpm.04}    & .36{\smaller\textpm.07}   & 2.57{\smaller\textpm.13(85.6\%)}   & 4.27{\smaller\textpm.14(91.3\%)}   & 13.71{\smaller\textpm.38(97.3\%)}    & .81{\smaller\textpm.16(54.3\%)}   & \hfil-                                                           & \hfil-                 \\        
                                      & GB     & .65{\smaller\textpm.11}    & .67{\smaller\textpm.13}   & 9.96{\smaller\textpm.30(93.4\%)}   & 20.25{\smaller\textpm2.17(96.7\%)} & 31.08{\smaller\textpm.43(97.9\%)}    & 1.36{\smaller\textpm.24(52.2\%)}  & \hfil-                                                           & \hfil-                 \\ \hline        
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{SignLang}}    & CNN    & .01{\smaller\textpm.01}    & .01{\smaller\textpm.01}   & \hfil-                             & \hfil-                             & 17.83{\smaller\textpm.90(99.9\%)}    & .22{\smaller\textpm.12(95.4\%)}   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.25{\smaller\textpm.09(96.0\%)}}   & .24{\smaller\textpm.09(95.8\%)}   \\        
                                      & RF     & .08{\smaller\textpm.02}    & .09{\smaller\textpm.03}   & .39{\smaller\textpm.06(79.4\%)}    & 1.74{\smaller\textpm.08(95.4\%)}   & 16.88{\smaller\textpm.66(99.5\%)}    & .19{\smaller\textpm.06(57.8\%)}   & \hfil-                                                           & \hfil-                 \\        
                                      & GB     & .08{\smaller\textpm.03}    & .08{\smaller\textpm.02}   & 4.05{\smaller\textpm0.18(98.0\%)}  & 5.96{\smaller\textpm.17(98.6\%)}   & 30.97{\smaller\textpm.17(99.7\%)}    & .47{\smaller\textpm.04(82.9\%)}   & \hfil-                                                           & \hfil-                 \\ \hline        
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Fashion}}     & CNN    & .79{\smaller\textpm.13}    & .76{\smaller\textpm.13}   & \hfil-                             & \hfil-                             & 7.33{\smaller\textpm.51(89.2\%)}     & 1.93{\smaller\textpm.20(59.0\%)}  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.84{\smaller\textpm.11(5.9\%)}}    & .88{\smaller\textpm.15(10.2\%)}   \\        
                                      & RF     & .74{\smaller\textpm.16}    & .79{\smaller\textpm.10}   & .91{\smaller\textpm.11(18.6\%)}    & 3.74{\smaller\textpm.12(80.2\%)}   & 3.45{\smaller\textpm.31(78.5\%)}     & 1.08{\smaller\textpm.15(31.4\%)}  & \hfil-                                                           & \hfil-                 \\        
                                      & GB     & .73{\smaller\textpm.13}    & .73{\smaller\textpm.08}   & 3.80{\smaller\textpm.20(80.7\%)}   & 5.71{\smaller\textpm3.91(87.2\%)}  & 3.90{\smaller\textpm.46(81.2\%)}     & 1.06{\smaller\textpm.14(31.1\%)}  & \hfil-                                                           & \hfil-                 \\ \hline        
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{CIFAR-10}}    & CNN    & 1.27{\smaller\textpm.19}   & 1.20{\smaller\textpm.15}  & \hfil-                             & \hfil-                             & 3.57{\smaller\textpm.40(64.4\%)}     & 5.99{\smaller\textpm.26(78.7\%)}  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5.16{\smaller\textpm.22(75.3\%)}}   & 5.16{\smaller\textpm.43(75.3\%)} \\        
                                      & RF     & 1.15{\smaller\textpm.24}   & 1.19{\smaller\textpm.23}  & 3.25{\smaller\textpm.28(64.6\%)}   & 4.59{\smaller\textpm.24(74.9\%)}   & 2.99{\smaller\textpm.26(61.5\%)}     & 2.51{\smaller\textpm.39(54.1\%)}  & \hfil-                                                           & \hfil-                 \\        
                                      & GB     & 1.25{\smaller\textpm.21}   & 1.31{\smaller\textpm.16}  & 7.57{\smaller\textpm.25(83.4\%)}   & 8.39{\smaller\textpm.18(85.1\%)}   & 2.70{\smaller\textpm.34(53.7\%)}     & 2.80{\smaller\textpm.24(55.3\%)}  & \hfil-                                                           & \hfil-                 \\ \hline        
                           
\end{tabular}}
\label{tab:mainresult}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Would need you to help me to solve this weird exception, because I don't see extra "\"

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe I overlook something, but what is the idea of using `\multicolumn{1}{c}{`...`}` inside a `c` column cell?

Comment: Please make you code snippet compilable, that is: add the document class and packages needed for this code. I cannot reproduce your problem (after having added the `rotating` package and some replacement definitions for `\sep`, `\stab` and `\smaller`). So, the problem might be due to the some of the other packages you use. WIthout knowing these, it is hard to help you.

Comment: I found the source of the problem : 
this package "\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}" collides with the "\usepackage{rotating}", any suggestions?